# Machine Learning: Is it better to retrain a model if the loss stagnates at a high value?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

Meaning to say if during training you have set your learning rate too high and you had unfortunately reached a local minimum where the value is too high, is it good to retrain with a lower learning rate or should you start from a higher learning rate for the poor-performing model, in hopes that the loss will escape the local minimum?

Comment: This can't be answered for the general case. Both approaches can work and fail. It's always dependent on the NN + data. Usually one uses a small fraction of the dataset to tune the learning-rate, which might also fail (in nonconvex optimization) but this is a valid approach in the convex-setting backed up by theory (we are using algorithms for training which were developed for convex optimization after all; so it works quite good in practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strict sense, you don't have to retrain as you can continue training with a lower learning rate (this is called a learning shedule). A very common approach is to lower the learning rate (by usually dividing by 10) each time the loss stagnates or becomes constant.

Another approach is to use an optimizer that scales the learning rate with the gradient magnitude, so the learning rate naturally decays as you get closer to the minima. Examples of this are ADAM, Adagrad and RMSProp.

In any case, make sure to find the optimal learning rate on a validation set, this will considerably improve performance and make learning faster. This applies to both plain SGD and with any other optimizer.

Comment: Still choosing a better learning rate has improved various models of mine by quite a lot even though I was using learning rate scheduling and / or ADAM.

Comment: I would also say, that tuned-SGD (parameters) will be better than ADAM and co. in most cases (with careful hyperparameter-optimization; if there are enough resources to do that). Most well-cited papers use vanilla SGD (and often explain the chosing; most of the time: faster training) for the final learning-task, often even without momentum.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz Yes I agree, I forgot about it :)